# org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.7.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've created a new springboot project using spring Initializer. When i view it in vs code i get an error in `pom.xml` on the `Parent` tag saying

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
> com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.7.3 failed
> to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a
> previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and
> resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has
> elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer
> artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.7.3
> from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
> repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local
> POM`

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

   </project>
```

Can somebody help please.

Comment: remove the directory from your local m2 repository and try to build again

Comment: Sorry, Which directory are you reffering to

Comment: in your user home directory should be a .m2 folder in this a repository and there the `org/spring-framework-boot/2.7.3